# tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset: ValueError: `label_name` provided must be one of the columns

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kaggle

I am trying to construct a dataset to use in Keras for the Titanic example on Kaggle.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/titanic/train.csv")

all_columns = ['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'] # all the columns names present in the csv

feature_columns = ['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'] # columns that I want to use as features for the training part


train_data = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    "/kaggle/input/titanic/train.csv",
    batch_size=12,
    column_names=all_columns,
    select_columns=feature_columns,
    label_name='Survived', # name of the 'label' column
    na_value="?",
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=False)
```

But when compiling, I get this error:

> ```
> 495   if label_name is not None and label_name not in column_names:
> 496     raise ValueError("`label_name` provided must be one of the columns.")
> 497 
> 498   def filename_to_dataset(filename):
> ```
>
> ValueError: `label_name` provided must be one of the columns.

But, as you can see *label_name* value is 'Survived' and it's present in *all_columns* (there also to *column_names*)

Any idea ?

Best

Aymeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label_name` must be included in the `select_columns`

Try:

```
train_data = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    "/kaggle/input/titanic/train.csv",
    batch_size=12,
    column_names=all_columns,
    select_columns=feature_columns + ['Survived'],
    label_name='Survived', # name of the 'label' column
    na_value="?",
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=False)
```